# How to work with Fragments using 100% java code? (without xml)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm trying to develop and app using 100% and only java code, without .xml files. I just want to understand how to achieve it. I want to achieve it also without extending Fragment class, just using Fragment as a layout container.

I finally got it but i don't like the approach, as i must create an extension class of Fragment with a special method for setting the View of the Fragment.

I don't like it. It whould be munch better if Fragment has a way to set the view programatically, something like for example:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setView(new TextView());
```

It is possible to do it? or the only way to achieve this is with my solution?

This is my working sample code with two classes:

```
public class BasicActivityWithFragment extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setId(1);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("prueba fragment todo por codigo java");

        CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment();
        fragment.setView(tv);
        fragmentTransaction.add(ll.getId(), fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        setContentView(ll);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment{
    View view;

    public CustomFragment(){
        super();
    }

    public void setView(View view){
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not creating the `View` in the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method, instead of in the `Activity`?

Comment: please, read the question, i need to achieve it using only ONE class, without extending Fragment

Comment: I did read the question, and that's not what it said. It said you want to do it without an XML layout.

Comment: Why would you try to do that? That is terrible. Fragments provide you already with a callback to create a `View` --> `onCreateView()`.  You are supposed to extend them, that's what they have been designed for.

Comment: Setting the `View` from outside the `Fragment` goes completely against the purpose of having `Fragments` in the first place. Why do you want to use `Fragments` in a way that makes them completely pointless?

Comment: @NullPointerException is strongly discourage you to inflate view outside of Activity/Fragment since they are tightly coupled with them. You'll certainly end up leaking views...

Comment: That simply cannot work. A `View` can't just be shared or passed between `Activities`. Not without breaking a lot of stuff and causing memory leaks.

Comment: It's working doesn't mean it doesn't leak. Sending views from Activity to Fragment is simply a bad design. Fragment are re-usable, lower level, components of an Activity. Therefore, Fragment are meant to be self-inflate their views. If you want to give parameters to Fragments, use the setArguments(Bundle) function instead.

Comment: No it can't work. You may just not notice or care about all the problems. And unless you specifically use the Application Context to create `Views` you WILL create memory leaks. But styling and theming and a whole bunch of other related things would be completely destroyed if you don't properly inflate a `View` inside an `Activity` with the `Context` of the `Activity`.

Comment: Also what are you trying to achieve? `Fragments` like you are trying to use them have no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: Listen to me and @SimonMarquis. This just can't work. Even if you may not notice any problems right now, there are huge issues with this approach.

Comment: first I would strongly, but REALLY strong advise against not using XML. But as it's for a code generator, maybe. What you probably looking to do is to generate class(es) that can create the view hierarchy for you using some interface like `view createView(Context)`. You generate as many classes of those as different views you need. Then you can pass to the fragment bundle the `Generated.class` (it's serializable) and let a base fragment get the class from the bundle call the constructor and call `generator.createView(getActivity());` But as others comment. This all sounds like bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create an anonymous Fragment and override this method:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment() {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(container.getContext());
            tv.setText("prueba fragment todo por codigo java");
            return tv;
        }
    };
```

But this comes with a lint warning:

> Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static

Comment: please, read the question, i need to achieve it using only ONE class, without extending Fragment